# I want to get data stored in cache created using Apache ignite without running the console application

Tags: c#, .net, ignite

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
        { 
            var ignite = Ignition.Start();
            var cache = ignite.GetOrCreateCache<int, string>("my-cache");
            cache.Put(1, "Hello, World");
            Console.WriteLine(cache.Get(1));
        }
```

In the above code when the Ignite node is getting started, Cache is created and I am able to get cache also but everytime I need to start the console application to get that cache. Is there any way to get the data from above cache next time without starting the console application once it is created. Please suggest.

Comment: Please clarify how `web application` is related to this code? Ignite does not depend on anything web-related, you can use it in any kind of application - console, desktop, web, and so on.

Comment: Put the code in a console app rather than a web app.

Comment: I have edited the question. I am new to apache ignite cache. Please suggest me how can I use this console app to get the cache data

Comment: Does your code work? I don't understand the question.

Comment: Yes, Code is working but my Question is Is that any way that I can use the cache from above console app in another web application in dot net and Do I need to start the Ignite node everytime to create the same cache again and again @mjwills

Comment: `Is that any way that I can use the cache from above console app in another web application in dot net` Copy and paste the code over to the web app?

Comment: But everytime I need to start the Ignite node which consumes time. For example if I am getting the cache output from a sql query that has complex calculation and to prevent the calls to database I am storing the result in Ignite cache but If I need to start the Ignite node again and again to get the cache then it will take the same time which I do not want and I need replacement for that situation @mjwills

Comment: I am not sure what you want here - you want the ability to use a cache without starting the cache up or connecting to it in some way? Umm, that isn't generally how computers work.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use thin client to connect to existing cluster:

https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/thin-clients/dotnet-thin-client

Comment: When I am trying to use thin client then I get exception "Failed to connect thin client connection" @alamar

Comment: Do you happen to run a stand-alone Ignite node at the time?

Comment: I just want to use ignite cache to create cache and to consume that cache in .net application to increase the performance speed @alamar

Comment: Maybe you need to start a stand-alone node then, and use ClientMode (thick client) in your .Net code?

Comment: Can you please give me any example to do so @alamar

Comment: Check out https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/starting-nodes#starting-client-nodes

Comment: Above link is only about starting and stopping nodes @alamar

Comment: What else do you need to do? I don't think you have specified anything else.

Comment: Do I need to call Ignition.start() everytime to create cache or is there any way that I can get the caches next time from memory when I start my application @alamar

Comment: You need to start an Ignite node every time when you need to use Ignite caching. If you use native persistence, the caches will already be available.

Comment: So you mean to say I need to use Ignite Persistance @alamar

Comment: It depends on your use case, which I don't know.